# Why are my strings not being compared correctly

Tags: c#, string

I don't understand why this is having issues comparing these strings. I am reading in text files, for each text file every line is being read into an array. 
Using a foreach loop i'm going through each line of the array to compare the first two values of the line. Depending on the value I then need to replace part of the string with a different value. I already know that the first two values from the substring in the first line return "01" but when debugging it is always picking up my else statement saying it didn't work. Can anyone enlighten me?

```
foreach (var i in files)
        {
            string[] lines;
            lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(i);

            foreach(string j in lines)
            {

                string str1 = "01";
                string sub = j.Substring(0, 2);
                if(sub.ToString().Equals(str1))
                {
                    j.Remove(45, 2);
                    j.Insert(45, "0");
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Didn't work");
                    Console.Read();

                }

            }
```

Comment: Please read the [`String.Remove`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.remove?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_String_Remove_System_Int32_) docs; in C# strings are immutable; all string functions return new strings, they do not (and cannot) change an existing string.

Comment: Also, there is no need to call `.ToString()` on a string. It already is a string :)

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve]? Here's a link to your code working for a string array: https://dotnetfiddle.net/BxG76d

Comment: Ignore the .ToString() part, that was me getting annoyed and trying any which thing I could think of lol.

Comment: Okay, it looks like the reason I thought it was working was because in the output file nothing was change. Is there a way for me to go through the array and replace these values and output it to a txt file? It's basically like scrubbing the file except at specific places. Would I have to build a stringbuilder for each file and as it's going through each line, replace it and then add it to the original stringBuilder?

Comment: The strings are immutable, but the array is not. If you iterate using an index, you can replace the contents of the current array element with the edited version.

Comment: You should probably use StringBuilder to modify the data in place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see documentation for `string.Remove()` and `string.Insert()` methods. They don't alter the existing `string`, simply create a new `string` and return the newly created `string`.

So, with that in mind, you can do a small modification like this. I've also edited the method a little bit so it's more general.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ReplaceFileContent(@"Input.txt", "01", 45, 2, "0");
    Console.ReadLine();
}

public static void ReplaceFileContent(string file, string find, int replaceAt, int replaceLen, string replaceWith)
{
    var lines = File.ReadAllLines(file).ToList();

    if (lines != null && lines.Count > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.Count; i++)
        {
            if (lines[i].Substring(0, find.Length) == find)
            {
                lines[i] = lines[i].Remove(replaceAt, replaceLen);
                lines[i] = lines[i].Insert(replaceAt, replaceWith);
            }
        }
    }

    File.WriteAllLines(file, lines);
}
```

Obviously you'll have to do some error handling, such as check if each line is at least longer than `replaceAt` + `replaceLen`, and other things like that.

Comment: We posted, at the same time. This is cleaner, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I was able to get it working. Thank you for the comments they really did help. Even though I read/heard about strings being immutable, it is still a concept I forget (I'm not a full time programmer).

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"Some Directory");
        int counter = 0;

        foreach (var i in files)
        {

            string[] lines;
            lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(i);



            for(int j=0;j<lines.Length;j++)
            {
                StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();

                string str1 ="";
                string str2 = "";
                string fullLine = lines[j];
                string sub = lines[j].Substring(0, 2);
                if(sub.Equals("01"))
                {
                    str1 = fullLine.Remove(44, 2);
                    str2 = str1.Insert(45, "0");
                    str.Append(str2);
                }
                else if(sub.Equals("02"))
                {
                    str1=fullLine.Remove(2, 2);
                    str2 = str1.Insert(2, "0");
                    str.Append(str2);
                }
                else if(sub.Equals("99"))
                {
                    str.Append(lines[j]);
                }

                lines[j] = str.ToString();

            }

            System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(someDirectory, lines);
            counter++;


        }




    }
}
```